# What percentage of data is used for cross validation with trainControl()

Tags: cross-validation

I used the following for cross-validation and expand grid function to train a caret rf model.

```
control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', 
                    number=10, 
                    repeats=3)
```

Is it possible to know what percentage of the training data is used in the cross-validation to generate rmse value for a particular training run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for `trainControl`:

```
p   For leave-group out cross-validation: the training percentage
```

Above that,  you can see that the default is `p = 0.75`